# Resizing a DXGI Resource or Texture2D in SharpDX

Tags: directx-11, sharpdx

I want to resize a screen captured using the Desktop Duplication API in SharpDX. I am using the [Screen Capture sample code from the SharpDX Samples repository](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct3D11.1/ScreenCapture/Program.cs), relevant portion follows:.

```cs
SharpDX.DXGI.Resource screenResource;
OutputDuplicateFrameInformation duplicateFrameInformation;

// Try to get duplicated frame within given time
duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(10000, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);

if (i > 0)
{
    // copy resource into memory that can be accessed by the CPU
    using (var screenTexture2D = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>()) 
    device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(screenTexture2D, screenTexture);

    // Get the desktop capture texture
    var mapSource = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(screenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);

    // Create Drawing.Bitmap
    var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var boundsRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

    // Copy pixels from screen capture Texture to GDI bitmap
    var mapDest = bitmap.LockBits(boundsRect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    var sourcePtr = mapSource.DataPointer;
    var destPtr = mapDest.Scan0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        // Iterate and write to bitmap...
```

I would like to resize the image much smaller than the actual screen size before processing it as a byte array. I do not need to save the image, just get at the bytes. I would like to do this relatively quickly and efficiently (e.g. leveraging GPU if possible).

I'm not able to scale during `CopyResource`, as the output dimensions are required to be the same as the input dimensions. Can I perform another copy from my `screenTexture2D` to scale? How exactly do I scale the resource - do I use a Swap Chain, Matrix transform, or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are fine resizing to a power of two from the screen, you can do it by:

- Create a smaller texture with `RenderTarget/ShaderResource` usage, and options `GenerateMipMaps`, same size of screen, mipcount > 1 (2 for having size /2, 3 for having /4...etc.).
- Copy the first mipmap of the screen texture to the smaller texture
- `DeviceContext.GenerateMipMaps` on the smaller texture
- Copy the selected mimap of the smaller texture (1: /2, 2: /4...etc.) to the staging texture (that should also be declared smaller, i.e. same size as the mipmap that is going to be used)

A quick hack on the original code to generate a /2 texture would be like this:

```cs
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        // # of graphics card adapter
        const int numAdapter = 0;

        // # of output device (i.e. monitor)
        const int numOutput = 0;

        const string outputFileName = "ScreenCapture.bmp";

        // Create DXGI Factory1
        var factory = new Factory1();
        var adapter = factory.GetAdapter1(numAdapter);

        // Create device from Adapter
        var device = new Device(adapter);

        // Get DXGI.Output
        var output = adapter.GetOutput(numOutput);
        var output1 = output.QueryInterface<Output1>();

        // Width/Height of desktop to capture
        int width = output.Description.DesktopBounds.Width;
        int height = output.Description.DesktopBounds.Height;

        // Create Staging texture CPU-accessible
        var textureDesc = new Texture2DDescription
                              {
                                  CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
                                  BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
                                  Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                                  Width = width/2,
                                  Height = height/2,
                                  OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                                  MipLevels = 1,
                                  ArraySize = 1,
                                  SampleDescription = { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
                                  Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging
                              };
        var stagingTexture = new Texture2D(device, textureDesc);

        // Create Staging texture CPU-accessible
        var smallerTextureDesc = new Texture2DDescription
        {
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            BindFlags = BindFlags.RenderTarget | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.GenerateMipMaps,
            MipLevels = 4,
            ArraySize = 1,
            SampleDescription = { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default
        };
        var smallerTexture = new Texture2D(device, smallerTextureDesc);
        var smallerTextureView = new ShaderResourceView(device, smallerTexture);

        // Duplicate the output
        var duplicatedOutput = output1.DuplicateOutput(device);

        bool captureDone = false;
        for (int i = 0; !captureDone; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                SharpDX.DXGI.Resource screenResource;
                OutputDuplicateFrameInformation duplicateFrameInformation;

                // Try to get duplicated frame within given time
                duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(10000, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);

                if (i > 0)
                {
                    // copy resource into memory that can be accessed by the CPU
                    using (var screenTexture2D = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>())
                        device.ImmediateContext.CopySubresourceRegion(screenTexture2D, 0, null, smallerTexture, 0);

                    // Generates the mipmap of the screen
                    device.ImmediateContext.GenerateMips(smallerTextureView);

                    // Copy the mipmap 1 of smallerTexture (size/2) to the staging texture
                    device.ImmediateContext.CopySubresourceRegion(smallerTexture, 1, null, stagingTexture, 0);

                    // Get the desktop capture texture
                    var mapSource = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(stagingTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None);

                    // Create Drawing.Bitmap
                    var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width/2, height/2, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                    var boundsRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width/2, height/2);

                    // Copy pixels from screen capture Texture to GDI bitmap
                    var mapDest = bitmap.LockBits(boundsRect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
                    var sourcePtr = mapSource.DataPointer;
                    var destPtr = mapDest.Scan0;
                    for (int y = 0; y < height/2; y++)
                    {
                        // Copy a single line 
                        Utilities.CopyMemory(destPtr, sourcePtr, width/2 * 4);

                        // Advance pointers
                        sourcePtr = IntPtr.Add(sourcePtr, mapSource.RowPitch);
                        destPtr = IntPtr.Add(destPtr, mapDest.Stride);
                    }

                    // Release source and dest locks
                    bitmap.UnlockBits(mapDest);
                    device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(stagingTexture, 0);

                    // Save the output
                    bitmap.Save(outputFileName);

                    // Capture done
                    captureDone = true;
                }

                screenResource.Dispose();
                duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();

            }
            catch (SharpDXException e)
            {
                if (e.ResultCode.Code != SharpDX.DXGI.ResultCode.WaitTimeout.Result.Code)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

        // Display the texture using system associated viewer
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, outputFileName)));

        // TODO: We should cleanp up all allocated COM objects here
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks man! One additional thing.. I'm also painting the mouse cursor, do you know any way to scale the cursor?

Comment: Is it possible to crop the desktop capture using the same technique? my goal is to get a screenshot on a small part of the screen with fastest way possible way.

Answer (score 5):

You need to take your original source surface in GPU memory and Draw() it on to a smaller surface.  This involves simple vector/pixel shaders, which some folks with simple needs would rather bypass.

I would look to see if someone made a sprite lib for sharpdx.  It should be a common "thing"...or using Direct2D (which is much more fun). Since D2D is just a user-mode library over D3D, it interops with D3D very easily.

I've never used SharpDx, but fFrom memory you would do something like this:

1.) Create an ID2D1Device, wrapping your existing DXGI Device (make sure your dxgi device creation flag has D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT)

2.) Get the ID2D1DeviceContext from your ID2D1Device

3.) Wrap your source and destination DXGI surfaces into D2D bitmaps with ID2D1DeviceContext::CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface

4.) ID2D1DeviceContext::SetTarget of your destination surface

5.) BeginDraw, ID2D1DeviceContext::DrawBitmap, passing your source D2D bitmap. EndDraw

6.) Save your destination

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pixelate example...

```
d2d_device_context_h()->BeginDraw();
d2d_device_context_h()->SetTarget(mp_ppBitmap1.Get());
D2D1_SIZE_F rtSize = mp_ppBitmap1->GetSize();
rtSize.height *= (1.0f / cbpx.iPixelsize.y);
rtSize.width *= (1.0f / cbpx.iPixelsize.x);
D2D1_RECT_F rtRect = { 0.0f, 0.0f, rtSize.width, rtSize.height };
D2D1_SIZE_F rsSize = mp_ppBitmap0->GetSize();
D2D1_RECT_F rsRect = { 0.0f, 0.0f, rsSize.width, rsSize.height };
d2d_device_context_h()->DrawBitmap(mp_ppBitmap0.Get(), &rtRect, 1.0f, 
D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, &rsRect);
d2d_device_context_h()->SetTarget(mp_ppBitmap0.Get());
d2d_device_context_h()->DrawBitmap(mp_ppBitmap1.Get(), &rsRect, 1.0f, 
D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR, &rtRect);
d2d_device_context_h()->EndDraw();
```

Where iPixelsize.xy is the size of the "pixelated pixel", note that i just use linear interpolation when shrinking the bmp and NOT when i reenlarge. This will generate a pixelation effect.